# Grouping Terms from a DocumentTermMatrix

Tags: r, tm

I have a csv file(contains "idNo" and "skillsList"). I want to cluster all the "idNo"'s falling under a "skillsList"

```
library(tm)
newCorpus=Corpus(VectorSource(inpDF))
DocTerMat=DocumentTermMatrix(newCorpus)
inspect(DocTerMat)
```

I loaded my csv file into R, and then prepared a "Document Term Matrix" All my "idNo" are Documents and all the "skillsList" are Terms. Got the Matrix correctly, but I do not know how to group the "idNo" with a  "skillsList".

Comment: possible duplicate of [grouping on tems in a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397186/grouping-on-tems-in-a-list-in-python)

Comment: This is using the R language so I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: You may have got the down vote because you did not provide a reproducible example.