# grouping on tems in a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, grouping

I have 60 records with a column "skillsList" "("skillsList" is a list of skills) and "IdNo".
I want to find out how many "IdNo's" have a skill in common.

How can I do it in python. I am not knowing how to take the count of a particular list item. Would appreciate any help.

```
>>> a = open("C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Book2.csv")
>>> type(a1)
<type 'str'>
```

Some of the text when I print a1

```
>>> a1
'IdNo, skillsList\n1,"u\'Training\', u\'E-Learning\', u\'PowerPoint\', u\'Teaching\', u\'Accounting\', u\'Team Management\', u\'Team Building\', u\'Microsoft Excel\', u\'Microsoft Office\', u\'Financial Accounting\', u\'Microsoft Word\', u\'Customer Service\'"\n2,"u\'Telecommunications\', u\'Data Center\', u\'ISO 27001\', u\'Management\', u\'BS25999\', u\'Technology\', u\'Information Technology...\', u\'Certified PMP\\xae\', u\'Certified BS25999 Lead...\'"\n3,"u\'Market Research\', u\'Segmentation\', u\'Marketing Strategy\', u\'Consumer Behavior\', u\'Experience Working with...\'"
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the structure used to save the columns?

Comment: can you show some examples of what is what in the code you got so far? (what are your "records" ? are they keys in a dictionary? or lists or something else?) Or give some example code of what you tried so far and how it turns out badly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it by yourself. you may use a dictionnary of skills , each item of the dic beeing inited to zero. Then iterate over your records and increment skill item when seen.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct = [{id: 1, skills: ['1', '2', '3']}, {...}]
for el in struct:
   if '1' in el.get('skills'):
      print 'id %s get this skill' % el.get('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a inverted index of skills. So you build a dictionary with each key as a skill name and the value of the key is a set of `IdNo`. That way you can also find out which `IdNo`s have some set of skills

The code would look like

```
skills = {}
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        items = [item.strip() for item in line.split(',')]
        idNo = items[0]
        skill_list = items[1:]
        for skill in skill_list:
            if skill in skills:
                skills[skill].add(idNo)
            else:
                skills[skill] = set([idNo, ])
```

Now you have `skills` dictionary which would look like

```
skills = {
    'Training': set(1,2,3),
    'Powerpoint': set(1,3,4),
    'E-learning': set(9,10,11),
    .....,
    .....,

}
```

Now you see that 1,3,4 have `Powerpoint` as a skill and if you want to know `idNo` who have both 'Training' and 'Powerpoint' skills you can do

```
skills['Powerpoint'].intersection(skills['Training'])
```

and if you want to know `idNo` who have either 'Training' or 'Powerpoint' skills you can do

```
skills['Powerpoint'].union(skills['Training'])
```